# Knockout - doubling value in a focused textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a knockout model with observable arrays bound to a table. I want to have a button that when clicked, doubles the focused textbox value. I want to do this without having a create a 'hasFocus' observable for every textbox or every ko observable. Couple of issues I experienced :-

- if the button just edits the value of the textbox directly using jQuery, the ko value does not get updated. I need a way to tell the button to change the underlying value
- if I focus on a textbox then click a button, the focus on the textbox is lost so client side also doesn't remember what textbox is focused

Comment: But won't the textbox loose focus when you click the button? The ui seems very un-intuitive. You would normally have a buuton for each textbox

Comment: I agree with @Wayne.  You either need a button for every textbox, or put a radio button next to the textboxes to indicate which one you want to work with.  Using focus for something like this is odd.  The user first has to click in the textbox, then on a button elsewhere on the page?

Comment: Also - updating the textbox value with jQuery - don't.  Update _the observable_ backing the textbox.  That's sort of the point of using knockout in the first place.

Comment: valid points - it also does seem unintuitive, but if you have ~50 textboxes it would be even wierder to put checkboxes or radio buttons below each of them. what's a better option?

Comment: @Ronbear Hard to say without seeing the design/features/functionality of the page.  Perhaps use Rune's answer combined with a visual style applied to the last focussed element if that's the way it needs to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an event binding on input on both focus and blur, setting and clearing an observable which tracks what input is active.
When the button is clicked you know which value to double

Comment: you could also disable the double button when nothing is in focus